# What is the fastest bash script to remove non retina display images (remove normal "png" only if "@2x.png" is present)?

Tags: bash

Most retina display images end in `@2x.png`, and generally have a normal `.png` in the same folder. So what would be the fastest way to find and remove `file.png` (recursively) only if `file@2x.png` exists in the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that would be possible with some convoluted `find -exec`, but I can't figure it out. This works for my little tests, though:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -name '*@2x.png' | sed 's/@2x//' | xargs echo rm
```

This finds all files ending in `@2x.png` in the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`), has sed remove the `@2x` bit and print `rm` and the file name. To actually remove them, is has to be `xargs rm`; to avoid being prompted, use `rm -f`, and to be prudent, use `rm -i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *parameter-substitution* to check for the file without `@2x` and remove the file containing `@2x` with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    printf "found '%s' -> rm '%s'\n" "${line/@2x}" "$line"
    # [ -f "${line/@2x}" ] && rm "$line"
done < <(find "$1" -type f -name "*@2x.png")
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash retinadel.sh dat
found 'dat/tmp/first.png' -> rm 'dat/tmp/first@2x.png'
...
```

(**note:** the code expects the `$path` as the first argument, and currently has the `rm` commented so you can test before actually attempting the removal. Always make sure you have a backup before removing valuable files...)

**note2:** you should add a test at the beginning of the script to validate at least 1-input for the path. e.g.:

```
[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate at least one argument provided
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s path\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}
```

That way, in the event the user (you) fail to provide a `path` as an argument, you receive:

```
$ bash retinadel.sh
error: insufficient input, usage: retinadel.sh path
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
find /path/to/folder -name '*@2.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'f=${0%@2.png}.png; [[ -f $f ]] && echo rm -- "$f"' {} \;
```

or, to limit the number of `bash` processes spawned:

```
find /path/to/folder -name '*@2.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do f=${i%@2.png}.png; [[ -f $f ]] && echo rm -- "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

Note that these commands will not remove anything, but just print to standard output the `rm` command that will be performed. Remove `echo` in front of `rm` if you're happy with it.